# Debian installation on Thinkpad tablet x201

Tags: debian, wifi, internet

I have installed debian on a Thinkpad tablet x201 via usb. The Debian loads actually succesfuly but there are a couple of things that didn't work, most important of which is i have no access to wireless internet. I am using ubuntu on another laptop and the internet is working fine on my other laptop, so it is not because of the router.
Can anyone help me fix this problem?

As information:

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit 
Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 06) Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2153]

Kernel driver in use: e1000e
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N
6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 
6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1311] ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 
Core 
Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] 
(rev 02)
```

**EDIT**

By the installation i got this:

`Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to oprerate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as USB stick or floppy. The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode`

and subsequently asked if i have such a media to load the firmware from, i choosed no. Does this firmware has something to do with my wifi problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install `firmware-iwlwifi` from the non-free repositories; this is the package which contains `iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode`. The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) provides detailed instructions. In summary:

- edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to add the non-free repository if necessary (you will end up with a line like `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free`)
- update the package information and install the firmware

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
  ```

This assumes you have a working Internet connection (using the Ethernet port on your laptop). If you don't, download [the package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/firmware-iwlwifi/download) on another computer and transfer it across, then install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-iwlwifi*.deb
```

Finally, in both cases reload the `iwlwifi` module:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: He doesn't have an internet connexion.

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R, I assumed the wired connection was usable but that might not be the case.

Comment: I have a wired connection. (i have edited my question, please see the EDIT)

Comment: @AmirTeymuri Good, Your can get your wifi working following the answer of Stephen, My answer is based on  your first question here :http://superuser.com/questions/1071694/no-wireless-internet-connection-in-debian/1071836#1071836

Comment: @StephenKitt When i run 'sudo dpkg -i firmware-iwlwifi*.deb' i get this error: dpkg: error processing archive firmware-iwlwifi*.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 firmware-iwlwifi*.deb

Comment: You need to have the package file in the current directory for that to work. If you have a working Internet connection just use the `apt-get` instructions.

Comment: What do you mean using `apt-get` instructions? Where can i find the instructions?

Comment: In my answer, the lines involving `/etc/apt/sources.list` and using `apt-get`...

Comment: Perfect, that all worked, i am sending you my thanks from a wifi internet! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download  the intel driver `e1000e` from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817)

Change to the driver `src` directory:

```
cp e1000e-3.3.3.tar /usr/local/src/
```

unzip the archive

```
tar zxf e1000e-3.3.3.tar
```

Install

```
make install
```

unload and load driver:

```
rmmod e1000e
modprobe e1000e
```

update `initramfs`

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot

Connect to the internet

Edit your `sources.list`

```
 nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

install `iwlwifi` driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Why install the e1000e driver? It's provided by the kernels used in Debian...

Answer (score 0):

The top-voted answer doesn't work (presumably) anymore.

This works:

- Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- Append `contrib non-free` to each of your sources.
- Then:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
  ```

... the X201 wireless NIC will then work.